# i want to make scroll in my aside without overflow because i have dropdown (translate to right )

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, overflow

my website height 100vh and i have an aside
in this aside i have list and every element in this list there is dropdown (dropright:when i hover in element dropdown translate from left to right  )
[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDuX7.png)
problem is:
i need to make scroll for aside but when i make scroll with overflow , dropdown hide
i need to make scroll without overflow
any help guys!

i need to make scroll for aside but when i make scroll with overflow , dropdown hide